# Creating a tagger that has more than one tag type for VS extension

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a Visual Studio extension that provides some features for a custom language. I've done simple syntax highlighting and I'm looking to move on to things like syntax error highlighting, brace matching, outlining, and such. The primary issue that I'm looking at right now is that these all require different tag types, which (so far as I can see) would require different taggers. However, I can't see any intuitive way to share information between the taggers, as all three of these things can be done in one parse of the content. I mean, I could parse it three times, but that doesn't sound like a good solution.

How can I return more than one tag type from a tagger (maybe use ITag?) or share information between more than one tagger?

My current structure is as such:

```
    internal class HighlightWordTagger : ITagger<ClassificationTag>
    {
        ITextBuffer TextBuffer;
        IClassificationType Keyword;
        IClassificationType Comment;
        IClassificationType Literal;

        // Probably a giant memory leak
        Dictionary<ITextSnapshot, List<TagSpan<ClassificationTag>>> SnapshotResults = new Dictionary<ITextSnapshot, List<TagSpan<ClassificationTag>>>();

        public HighlightWordTagger(ITextBuffer sourceBuffer, IClassificationTypeRegistryService typeService)
        {
            TextBuffer = sourceBuffer;

            TextBuffer.Changed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                LexSnapshot(args.After);

                TagsChanged(this, new SnapshotSpanEventArgs(new SnapshotSpan(args.After, new Span(0, args.After.Length))));
            };
            Keyword = typeService.GetClassificationType("WideKeyword");
            Comment = typeService.GetClassificationType("WideComment");
            Literal = typeService.GetClassificationType("WideLiteral");
        }

        public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<ClassificationTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
        {
            LexSnapshot(spans[0].Snapshot);
            foreach (var snapshotspan in SnapshotResults[spans[0].Snapshot])
            {
                foreach (var span in spans)
                {
                    if (snapshotspan.Span.IntersectsWith(span))
                    {
                        yield return snapshotspan;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Span SpanFromLexer(Lexer.Range range)
        {
            return new Span((int)range.begin.offset, (int)(range.end.offset - range.begin.offset));
        }

        void LexSnapshot(ITextSnapshot shot)
        {
            if (SnapshotResults.ContainsKey(shot))
                return;

            var lexer = new Lexer();
            var list = new List<TagSpan<ClassificationTag>>();
            SnapshotResults[shot] = list;
            lexer.Read(
                shot.GetText(),
                (where, what) =>
                {
                    if (what == Lexer.Failure.UnlexableCharacter)
                        return false;
                    var loc = new Span(
                        (int)where.offset,
                        (int)shot.Length - (int)where.offset
                    );
                    if (what == Lexer.Failure.UnterminatedComment)
                        list.Add(new TagSpan<ClassificationTag>(new SnapshotSpan(shot, loc), new ClassificationTag(Comment)));
                    if (what == Lexer.Failure.UnterminatedStringLiteral)
                        list.Add(new TagSpan<ClassificationTag>(new SnapshotSpan(shot, loc), new ClassificationTag(Literal)));
                    return false;
                }, 
                where =>
                {
                    // Clamp this so it doesn't go over the end when we add \n in the lexer.
                    where.end.offset = where.end.offset > shot.Length ? (uint)(shot.Length) : where.end.offset;
                    var loc = SpanFromLexer(where);
                    list.Add(new TagSpan<ClassificationTag>(new SnapshotSpan(shot, loc), new ClassificationTag(Comment)));
                },
                token => {
                    var location = SpanFromLexer(token.location);
                    if (token.type == Lexer.TokenType.String || token.type == Lexer.TokenType.Integer)
                    {
                        list.Add(new TagSpan<ClassificationTag>(new SnapshotSpan(shot, location), new ClassificationTag(Literal)));
                    }
                    if (lexer.IsKeyword(token.type))
                    {
                        list.Add(new TagSpan<ClassificationTag>(new SnapshotSpan(shot, location), new ClassificationTag(Keyword)));
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            );
        }

        public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged = delegate { };
    }
```

I could probably do a better job of not re-lexing so much, but that's for another question.

Comment: @Yvette: I only use lexing with one tag right now. I call into unmanaged code to lex and parse, and it does both simultaneously.

Comment: @Yvette: Yeah.. my comment wasn't actually very helpful. Let me post my structure.

Comment: It strikes me that you might be able to get some reuse if you implement `ITagger<T>` multiple times within the same class (for different `T`s). That way, there is at least an obvious way to "share information" between taggers - because it's the same class.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: But will VS actually request multiple tags from the one tagger? And will it only ask the ITaggerProvider for one ITagger<T> for multiple T? This is where I really dislike these magic frameworks that do everything for you- because you don't know what's done.

Comment: There's a reason I put it as a comment rather than an answer :-) I don't know, myself, whether it would definitely work - it was more a suggestion of the next experiment I would try if I was facing this issue.

Comment: It definitely only functions if the ITaggerProvider only provides a tagger that tags for one concrete type. Any attempt to provide multiple types fails.

Comment: I've never tried implementing VS extensions, but from your conversation here I wonder whether you would be able to create ICustomTagger that inherits from ITagger? Then add three properties that are the same as the once that you want to pass. When you instantiate an object that implements ICustomTagger also instantiate the properties. Passing ICustomTagger where ITagger is requested should be valid. Inside your code do type conversion to ICustomTagger and read the properties. Does this sound reasonable/feasible?

Comment: @Husein: Visual Studio will only act on a predefined tag, like ClassifierTag, if you explicitly export only ClassifierTag and inherit from only ITagger<ClassifierTag>. You can't get it to play ball with more than one tag type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your comment was the inspiration for my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up having to separate out these concerns. You can use `ITextBuffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty` to associate arbitrary objects of your choice with the text buffer. I ended up creating a separate lexer class, associating it with the text buffer, and then simply performing almost all the logic except the tagging there. Then in the implementation of each tagger, I simply poll the lexer for results, and then tag them. This permits multiple taggers to depend on the same lexer instance.

Considering that *most* lexers and parsers would produce more than one kind of tag, I'm surprised that VS makes you hack around so badly to produce this outcome.

Comment: +1 for ranting about VS extensibility. It requires *way* too much boilerplate, it is hard to debug (e.g. you can't set breakpoints on MEF attributes), it is *undiscoverable*, and things that should be built-in (e.g. brace matching) have to be added manually (or if they *are* built-in, how can we find them without access to the source code of VS?)

Answer (score 3):

As puppy said, you can use multiple separate taggers and they can reach each other through `GetOrCreateSingletonProperty`, but I assume there is no guarantee about the order in which the taggers will be created, so the initialization process may be inconvenient.

Meanwhile, I have been successful in combining multiple taggers in one class, and I even made a complete "sample language" to demonstrate this technique. Here it is:

```
/// <summary>Boilerplate factory class that associates <see cref="SampleLanguageForVS"/>,
/// and file extension .samplelang, with content type "Sample Language".</summary>
[Export(typeof(IClassifierProvider))]
[Export(typeof(ITaggerProvider))]
[TagType(typeof(ClassificationTag))]
[TagType(typeof(ErrorTag))]
[ContentType("Sample Language")]
internal class SampleLanguageForVSProvider : IClassifierProvider, ITaggerProvider
{
    [Export]
    [Name("Sample Language")] // Must match the [ContentType] attributes
    [BaseDefinition("code")]
    internal static ContentTypeDefinition _ = null;
    [Export]
    [FileExtension(".samplelang")]
    [ContentType("Sample Language")]
    internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition _1 = null;

    [Import] IClassificationTypeRegistryService _registry = null; // Set via MEF

    public static SampleLanguageForVS Get(IClassificationTypeRegistryService registry, ITextBuffer buffer)
    {
        return buffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty<SampleLanguageForVS>(
            delegate { return new SampleLanguageForVS(registry, buffer); });
    }
    public IClassifier GetClassifier(ITextBuffer buffer)
    {
        return Get(_registry, buffer);
    }
    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        return Get(_registry, buffer) as ITagger<T>;
    }
}

internal class SampleLanguageForVS : IClassifier,
    ITagger<ClassificationTag>,
    ITagger<ErrorTag>,
    IBackgroundAnalyzerImpl<object, IList<ITagSpan<ITag>>>
{
    protected IClassificationTypeRegistryService _registry;
    protected ITextBuffer _buffer;
    protected IClassificationType _commentType;
    protected ClassificationTag _outerParenTag;
    protected IList<ITagSpan<ITag>> _resultTags;
    protected BackgroundAnalyzerForVS<object, IList<ITagSpan<ITag>>> _parseHelper;

    public SampleLanguageForVS(IClassificationTypeRegistryService registry,ITextBuffer buffer)
    {
        _registry = registry;
        _buffer = buffer;
        _commentType = registry.GetClassificationType(PredefinedClassificationTypeNames.Comment);
        _outerParenTag = MakeTag(PredefinedClassificationTypeNames.Keyword);
        _parseHelper = new BackgroundAnalyzerForVS<object, IList<ITagSpan<ITag>>>(buffer, this, true);
    }
    ClassificationTag MakeTag(string name)
    {
        return new ClassificationTag(_registry.GetClassificationType(name));
    }

    #region Classifier (lexical analysis)

    public event EventHandler<ClassificationChangedEventArgs> ClassificationChanged;

    public IList<ClassificationSpan> GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan span)
    {
        List<ClassificationSpan> spans = new List<ClassificationSpan>();
        var line = span.Snapshot.GetLineFromPosition(span.Start);
        do {
            var cspan = GetLineClassification(line);
            if (cspan != null)
                spans.Add(cspan);

            if (line.EndIncludingLineBreak.Position >= span.Snapshot.Length) break;
            line = span.Snapshot.GetLineFromPosition(line.EndIncludingLineBreak.Position);
        } while (line.EndIncludingLineBreak < span.End.Position);
        return spans;
    }

    public ClassificationSpan GetLineClassification(ITextSnapshotLine line)
    {
        var span = new Span(line.Start.Position, line.Length);
        var sspan = new SnapshotSpan(line.Snapshot, span);
        int i;
        for (i = span.Start; i < line.Snapshot.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(line.Snapshot[i]); i++) { }
        if (i < line.Snapshot.Length && 
            (line.Snapshot[i] == '#' ||
             line.Snapshot[i] == '/' && i + 1 < line.Snapshot.Length && line.Snapshot[i+1] == '/'))
            return new ClassificationSpan(sspan, _commentType);
        return null;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Background analysis (the two taggers)

    public object GetInputSnapshot()
    {
        return null; // this example has no state to pass to the analysis thread.
    }
    public IList<ITagSpan<ITag>> RunAnalysis(ITextSnapshot snapshot, object input, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        List<ITagSpan<ITag>> results = new List<ITagSpan<ITag>>();
        // On analysis thread: produce classification tags for nested [(parens)]
        // and warning tags for backslashes.
        int parenLevel = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = snapshot[i];
            if (c == '\\')
                results.Add(new TagSpan<ErrorTag>(
                    new SnapshotSpan(snapshot, new Span(i, 1)),
                    new ErrorTag("compiler warning", "Caution: that's not really a slash, it's a backslash!!")));
            bool open = (c == '[' || c == '(');
            bool close = (c == ']' || c == ')');
            if (close) {
                if (parenLevel > 0)
                    parenLevel--;
                else {
                    results.Add(new TagSpan<ErrorTag>(
                        new SnapshotSpan(snapshot, new Span(i, Math.Min(2, snapshot.Length-i))),
                        new ErrorTag("syntax error", "Caution: closing parenthesis without matching opener")));
                }
            }
            if ((open || close) && parenLevel == 0)
                results.Add(new TagSpan<ClassificationTag>(
                    new SnapshotSpan(snapshot, new Span(i, 1)), 
                    _outerParenTag));
            if (open)
                parenLevel++;
        }
        return results;
    }
    public void OnRunSucceeded(IList<ITagSpan<ITag>> results)
    {
        _resultTags = results;
        // We don't know which tags changed unless we do some fancy diff, so
        // act as if everything changed.
        if (TagsChanged != null) // should always be true
            TagsChanged(this, new SnapshotSpanEventArgs(new SnapshotSpan(_buffer.CurrentSnapshot, new Span(0, _buffer.CurrentSnapshot.Length))));
    }

    #endregion

    #region ITagger<ClassificationTag> and ITagger<ErrorTag> Members

    IEnumerable<ITagSpan<ErrorTag>> ITagger<ErrorTag>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        return GetTags<ErrorTag>(spans);
    }
    IEnumerable<ITagSpan<ClassificationTag>> ITagger<ClassificationTag>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        return GetTags<ClassificationTag>(spans);
    }
    public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<TTag>> GetTags<TTag>(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans) where TTag : ITag
    {
        if (_resultTags == null)
            return null;

        // TODO: make more efficient for large files with e.g. binary search
        int start = spans[0].Start.Position, end = spans[spans.Count-1].End.Position;
        return _resultTags.Where(ts => ts.Span.End >= start && ts.Span.Start <= end).OfType<ITagSpan<TTag>>();
    }

    public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

All that is missing above is `using` statements (see the [complete source file](https://github.com/qwertie/Loyc/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%20Integration/LoycExtensionForVs/SampleLanguage.cs)) and the [`BackgroundAnalyzerForVS`](https://github.com/qwertie/Loyc/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%20Integration/LoycExtensionForVs/BackgroundAnalyzerForVS.cs) class. If you plug this code into a vsix project you'll get "lexing", delayed "parsing", warning and error tags. Demo file:

```
Open this in Visual Studio to see "sample" syntax highlighting.
  // Backslashes are underlined.
  \\ <-- Such as those ones.
When you start a parenthetical (like this) the parens are highlighted, 
but ([nested parens (like this)]) are not highlighted.
# Do not write a closing ")" without an opening "(".
```